# YouTube auto-quality removal

Tags: youtube

I love to just put song playlist and listen to songs, but auto-quality always changes my video quality to 720p, which wasn't such a problem before but with 60fps thing added, my videos start to lag and so do the songs. It's probably because I have 100mb/sec internet but internet this time is not the problem—it's my PC. I got new monitor lately that is 1920x1080 so add that with HD video on 60fps with my weak processor and video card outcome is pretty sad. Because I'm a pretty busy guy and I just want my songs to play without problems, I can't constantly change video quality whenever songs change.

So far I have tried:

- Changing YouTube settings to *slow internet, never play HD videos*. (Of course it still has the automatic settings and still changes to 720p.)
- Tried downloading Chrome extensions, which didn't work as well.
- Changed videos from being in that big screen mode to that little one where playlist is right from video. This didn't help as well.

I have ran out of ides on what to do… Do I really need to download Firefox or something else just for YouTube to be able to listen to music?

Comment: Have you tried SmartVideo Chrome extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smartvideo-for-youtube/lnkdbjbjpnpjeciipoaflmpcddinpjjp?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

You can use Yays(yet another youtube script) to scale and playing videos quality. Please check the lin k below for detailed info on this.

http://www.ghacks.net/2013/03/15/how-to-set-a-default-video-size-and-quality-on-youtube/

Comment: Unfortunetly, Yays is not downloadable anymore..